# I need to retrieve the invoice-due_date and the invoice_total.

Tags: mysql

I need to retrieve the invoice-due_date and the invoice_total.

Then in the query write the condition of 10% of the value of  invoice_total  and
other result with a plus UP to 10% of the value of  invoice_total. All in the same statement.

Txs

Answer (score 0):

```
select invoice-due_date, invoice_total, invoice_total+invoice_total*.1+(UP)*.1 as newprice

from table
```